# Time measurment in devcpp

Tags: c++

```
__int64 start;
long double freq, tm;

void time_start()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
    std::cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";

    freq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    start = li.QuadPart;
}

void time_stop()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    tm = (double) (li.QuadPart - start)/freq;
}
```

These are the functions I use to measure execution time. They work as expected in VS 2012, but in devcpp they always display the same time - something e-317...

The headers I use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Which compiler does your DevC++ use?

Comment: Maybe you could recommend me some other time counting function?